# Jailbreak detection with installed xCon

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I have question about detecting Jailbreak on iOS. I used a couple things to detect it and they are working fine but when I’m installing xCon my app is not detecting Jailbreak any more. I've used the following techniques:

- checking if cydia exists
- checking for cydia app scheme
- checking for writing outside sandbox
- checking for existence of symbolic links
- checking fork() function
- checking dyld functions 
  How can I protect my app from xCon tweaks? Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: please have look into https://www.threatmetrix.com/  but not free.

Comment: Tweaks can effectively change the code of your program. As such, nothing you can do will withstand the will of someone determined do break your detection.

Comment: Well, those checks are ok.  But you can do a lot today with "jailed" devices with `Frida`.  Why not try an open source tool with more detections: `https://github.com/securing/IOSSecuritySuite`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anything what I can do?

Not really.

In a jailbroken environment, any part of your app can be rewritten on the fly. So any detection you implement can just be jumped over.

You can certainly *try* to make it harder for them to find and circumvent such check by making your app more obscure, employing obfuscation, using syscalls directly rather than relying on host libraries, etc, etc, but as long as the system can *execute* your checks, someone with enough time and willpower can *track them down, reverse engineer how they work, and neuter them*.