# Detect JailBroken Phone in IOS with xCon packages Installed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, jailbreak

I am finding multiple post that are explaining the generic way to detect the JailBroken phone methods.

One of the close reference is : https://github.com/masbog/isJB

However did not detect Jailbroken when tested on xCon installed device.

Any leads how we can detect as we have a finance app that needs to be blocked if device is JB and even if xCon installed.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Something similar question with no answer yet, however we see other finance apps able to detect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697765/jailbreak-detection-with-installed-xcon

Comment: As stated in the post you linked to, that's not really possible. Your app can be patched before it even begins to run. How could you possibly protect against that?

Answer (score 0):

- Swift jailbreak check:

  ```
  static func isJailbroken() -> Bool {

  guard let cydiaUrlScheme = NSURL(string: "cydia://package/com.example.package") else { return false }
  if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(cydiaUrlScheme as URL) {
      return false
  }

  #if arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)
      // This is a Simulator not an idevice
      return false
  #endif
  let fileManager = FileManager.default
  if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: "/Applications/Cydia.app") ||
      fileManager.fileExists(atPath: "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib") ||
      fileManager.fileExists(atPath: "/bin/bash") ||
      fileManager.fileExists(atPath: "/usr/sbin/sshd") ||
      fileManager.fileExists(atPath: "/etc/apt") ||
      fileManager.fileExists(atPath: "/usr/bin/ssh") ||
      fileManager.fileExists(atPath: "/private/var/lib/apt") {
      return true
  }
  if canOpen(path: "/Applications/Cydia.app") ||
      canOpen(path: "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib") ||
      canOpen(path: "/bin/bash") ||
      canOpen(path: "/usr/sbin/sshd") ||
      canOpen(path: "/etc/apt") ||
      canOpen(path: "/usr/bin/ssh") {
      return true
  }
  let path = "/private/" + NSUUID().uuidString
  do {
      try "anyString".write(toFile: path, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
      try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: path)
      return true
  } catch {
      return false
  }
  }

  static func canOpen(path: String) -> Bool {
      let file = fopen(path, "r")
      guard file != nil else { return false }
      fclose(file)
      return true
  }
  ```